# Multi-threading with iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, multithreading

I'm using a separate NSAutoReleasePool for my thread

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; 
[self bulkyFunction]; // time consuming op
[self performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(doneAll) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
[pool release];
```

and I call a function (bulkyFunction) that allocates two strings.

```
    currentTitle = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    currentSummary = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
```

I release them after using.

This thread is called periodically. But when it's called the second time, accessing currentTitle crashes.

Is it because my [pool release] statement releases currentTitle which has already been released by [currentTitle release] statement?
Because, if the [currentTitle release] is commented out, there is no problem. But i'm worried about memory leaks.

Please advice.

Answer (score 4):

`[pool release]` will not release `currentTitle` unless you call `[currentTitle autorelease]` 
somewhere. I think it would be helpful if you posted the entirety of `bulkyFunction`.